# ionic update from 2.0 to 3.9

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm trying to migrate a project I made with ionic 2 last year, to ionic 3.9.

I'm having troubles with the ionic-native sqlite.

I updated my CLI and I did the steps mentionned here to update : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/guide-how-to-update-to-ionic-3-x/87516

I think I did what was mentionned in the documentation. I added this import in the `app.module.ts` file :

```
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
```

And I added the 2 objects in the providers entry of the NgModule :

```
@NgModule({
    // ... 
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        SQLite, SQLiteObject,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
    ]
})
```

Also, I have 1 class that included the sqlite object, and I replace the previous with this :

```
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
```

The previous import was :

```
import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';
```

Unfortunately, when I try to build with `ionic cordova build android`, i get :

```
// ... 
[18:34:51]  preprocess finished in 1 ms 
[18:34:51]  webpack started ... 
[18:34:54]  copy finished in 10.43 s 
[18:34:59]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[18:34:59]  Error: ./src/pages/home/home.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ionic-native/file' in 
            '/Users/julianlecalvez/Documents/SFR/biometo-v4/src/pages/home' resolve '@ionic-native/file' in 
            '/Users/julianlecalvez/Documents/SFR/biometo-v4/src/pages/home' Parsed request is a module using description 
            file: /Users/julianlecalvez/Documents/SFR/biometo-v4/package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/home) Field 
            'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /Users/julianlecalvez/Documents/SFR/biometo-v4/package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/home) resolve as 
            module looking for modules in /Users/julianlecalvez/Documents/SFR/biometo-v4/node_modules using description 
            file: /Users/julianlecalvez/Documents/SFR/biometo-v4/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
// I got the same errors for other native plugins (File & Google Analytics)
```

Here is my `ionic info` :
I

```
onic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.3.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.0.0, ios 4.3.1
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (11 plugins total)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 25.1.3 (/Users/julianlecalvez/Library/Android/sdk/)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.1
   NodeJS            : v8.9.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 5.5.1
   OS                : macOS High Sierra
```

And here is my `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "author": "xxx",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.15.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "2.5.1",
    "prismic.io": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "xxx",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your package.json does not list your ionic-native wrappers you seem to be using. You will need to install them

Comment: indeed ! but i had troubles installing them with my node 8 and npm 5. I fixed this by upgrading to node 10 and npm 6 (the current LTS). It seems to work perfectly ! Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

when you install ionic plugin ,if you don't appoint version, it will install the latest version. but the latest version is for ionic4, so you can't use it in ionic3, so you must install @ionic-native pulgin by appoint version.

see plugin docs of ionic3 not ionic4 or 5.